# Cannot Visualize Smoke on Stage

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-animation

I am creating an animated stage scene using Matplotlib where I need to visualize smoke on the stage. However, despite my efforts, the smoke is not visible on the stage.

I'm using the Matplotlib patches.Circle to create and update the smoke at each frame in the animation loop. I increase the radius of the smoke and decrease its alpha value to create the effect of smoke expanding and fading. I also update the position of the smoke to give it some movement.

Here is the sampleclass.py(includes the stage and other implementation) -

```
    from classes import *
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
from SmokeMachine1 import SmokeMachine


def main():
    no_lights = 5
    fig, (sub1, sub2) = plt.subplots(2, 1, gridspec_kw={'height_ratios': [1, 10]}, figsize=(7, 7))
    colors = ["violet", "darkviolet", "purple", "darkmagenta", "blueviolet"]
    lights = []
    beams_top = []
    beams_bot = []

    # Initialize SmokeMachine
    smoke_machine = SmokeMachine(intensity=0.2, position=(375, 62), direction=(0, 0.2))

    # List of start and end coordinates of the lasers
    laser_cords = [
        (np.array([0, 0]), np.array([500, 500])),
        (np.array([0, 0]), np.array([200, 800])),
        (np.array([0, 0]), np.array([500, 300])),
    ]
    laser2_cords = [
        (np.array([500, 0]), np.array([0, 1000])),
        (np.array([500, 0]), np.array([0, 700])),
        (np.array([500, 0]), np.array([0, 350])),
    ]

    # limits of the plot
    lim1 = (500, 500)
    lim2 = (500, 50)

    # set subplots 1 and 2 limits
    sub1.set_xlim(0, lim2[0])
    sub1.set_ylim(0, lim2[1])
    sub2.set_xlim(0, lim1[0])
    sub2.set_ylim(0, lim1[1])

    # props initialization
    # Singer Body
    body = Body(90, 62, 25, 75)
    sub2.add_patch(body.get_patch())
    # Guitarist Body
    body2 = Body(375, 62, 25, 70)
    sub2.add_patch(body2.get_patch())
    # Singer Head
    head = Head(25, 125, 20)
    sub2.add_patch(head.get_patch())
    # Guitarist Head
    head2 = Head(25, 125, 20)
    sub2.add_patch(head2.get_patch())

    # insert stage
    img = mpimg.imread('curtains.png')
    sub2.imshow(img, extent=[0, lim1[0], 0, lim1[1]], zorder=3, alpha=0.7)
    img = mpimg.imread('curtains-2.png')
    sub2.imshow(img, extent=[0, lim1[0], 0, lim1[1]], zorder=3, alpha=0.7)

    # backdrop
    img = mpimg.imread('spinaltap.png')
    sub2.imshow(img, extent=[0, lim1[0], 0, lim1[1]], zorder=1)

    # fill stage
    sub1.set_aspect("equal")
    sub1.fill([0, 500, 500, 0], [0, 0, 50, 50], color="maroon", alpha=0.8)
    sub2.set_aspect("equal")
    sub2.fill([0, 0, 500, 500], [0, 62, 62, 0], color="maroon", zorder=2)
    # Drum Set
    sub2.fill([200, 200, 300, 300], [62, 100, 100, 62], color="lightblue", zorder=1)
    sub2.text(250, 81, "LETS ROCK", ha='center', va='center', color="black", zorder=2, weight="bold")
    # Drummer Body
    sub2.fill([237.5, 237.5, 262.5, 262.5], [100, 125, 125, 100], color="red", zorder=1)
    # Drummer Head
    circle3 = patches.Circle((250, 120 + 20), 20, color='yellow', zorder=1)
    sub2.add_patch(circle3)

    # List of colors for each laser
    colors2 = ['red', 'aqua', 'lime', 'aqua', 'red', 'lime']

    # Initialize lasers with different colors
    lasers = [sub2.plot([], [], color=colors2[i % len(colors2)])[0] for i in range(len(laser_cords) + len(laser2_cords))]

    # Flag to track whether the lasers are plotted or removed
    plotted = False

    for i in range(no_lights):
        light = Light(colors[i], (i * 100 + 50, 25))
        lights.append(light)
        light.plot_lights(sub1)

    for i in range(no_lights):
        beam = Beam(colors[i], (i * 100 + 50, 490))
        beams_top.append(beam)
        beam.beams_top(sub2)

    for i in range(no_lights):
        beam = Beam(colors[i], (i * 100 + 50, 490))
        beams_bot.append(beam)
        beam.beams_bot(sub2)

    # Generate smoke
    smoke_machine.generate_smoke(sub2)

    # Main loop
    for j in range(30):

        # Update smoke
        smoke_machine.update(sub2)
        if smoke_machine.smoke is None:
            smoke_machine.generate_smoke(sub2)

        # Update position of the rectangles
        body.update(j, sub2)
        body2.update(j, sub2)

        # X and Y position of Circle
        head_x = body.x_pos + body.body.get_width() / 2
        head_y = body.body.get_y() + body.body.get_height() + head.radius
        head.update(head_x, head_y, sub2)

        head2_x = body2.x_pos + body2.body.get_width() / 2
        head2_y = body2.body.get_y() + body2.body.get_height() + head2.radius
        head2.update(head2_x, head2_y, sub2)

        for i, light in enumerate(lights):
            light.change_color(colors)
            light.plot_lights(sub1)
            beams_top[i].color = light.color
            beams_top[i].beams_top(sub2, rm_beam=True)
            beams_bot[i].color = light.color
            beams_bot[i].beams_bot(sub2, rm_beam=True)

        # Update position of the lasers
        if not plotted:
            for i, laser in enumerate(lasers):
                if i < len(laser_cords):
                    current_pos = laser_cords[i][0] + j * (laser_cords[i][1] - laser_cords[i][0])
                    laser.set_data([laser_cords[i][0][0], current_pos[0]], [laser_cords[i][0][1], current_pos[1]])
                else:
                    k = i - len(laser_cords)
                    current_pos = laser2_cords[k][0] + j * (laser2_cords[k][1] - laser2_cords[k][0])
                    laser.set_data([laser2_cords[k][0][0], current_pos[0]], [laser2_cords[k][0][1], current_pos[1]])
        else:
            for laser in lasers:
                laser.set_data([], [])

        if j >= len(laser_cords[0]):
            plotted = not plotted


        plt.pause(0.6)

    plt.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Here is the SmokeMachine1.py class -

```
import matplotlib.patches as patches


class SmokeMachine:
    def __init__(self, intensity, position, direction):
        self.intensity = intensity
        self.position = position
        self.direction = direction
        self.smoke = None
        self.smoke_radius = 0

    def generate_smoke(self, stage_subplot):
        if self.smoke:
            self.smoke.remove()
        self.smoke_radius = self.intensity * 10  # Arbitrary factor
        self.smoke = patches.Circle(self.position, self.smoke_radius, color='black', alpha=0.7)
        stage_subplot.add_patch(self.smoke)

    def update(self, stage_subplot):
        # Expand and fade the smoke
        print("Updating smoke...")
        self.smoke_radius = self.intensity * 10  # Arbitrary factor
        self.smoke.set_radius(self.smoke_radius)
        alpha = self.smoke.get_alpha() - 0.01  # Adjust fade speed as needed
        self.smoke.set_alpha(max(alpha, 0))

        # Move the smoke
        x, y = self.position
        dx, dy = self.direction
        self.position = (x + dx, y + dy)
        self.smoke.center = self.position

        # If the smoke has faded away completely, remove it from the subplot
        if self.smoke.get_alpha() <= 0:
            self.smoke.remove()
            self.smoke = None
```

Despite this, the smoke is not visible on the stage. I would appreciate it if anyone could point me in the right direction as to why the smoke is not appearing.

Comment: `NameError: name 'Body' is not defined`